# Route Resolver of Feature Module executes immediately

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a feature module in which I lazy load another module called "travel-details" which also contains its own routing. Inside the travel-details module the parent route has a route resolver which is intended to be executed whenever the upper feature module loads/activates the travel-details module. However, immediately when I load the the upper feature module, the route resolver is executed, even though the route of the travel-details module is not activated.

Why does the resolver activate immediately and how can I fix this?

upper feature module:
[image]

travel-details module:
[image]

Also nice to know:
The resolver only executes on the second time when the module is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you imported `TravelDetailsModule` in to `AppModule` ?
It can cause the issue.

If not try to give more code to be useful for investigation.

Comment: No, also it happens only on the second route acitvation of the parent module when it is already loaded once